# Using Raspberry Pi to make Internet TV box (Power on/off issue)

Tags: boot, power, kodi, power-management, internet

I need to make a box (STB), which when plugged into TV can display live streaming URLs and can be controlled from remote control. So that a user can have the same experience as of a traditional live TV. One way is to use a Raspberry Pi and make a custom software for that or use openElec with Kodi (XBMC Media Center). Attach a remote control also for easy operation. I am not clear about whether I can get the following features on Raspberry or not:

1. Power on/off with remote (Raspberry can go to standby, TV off)
2. In case of power outage, Raspberry will boot again. How much time will it take normally to boot? (I haven't used a Raspberry yet, hence asking)
3. Upon booting up or coming back from standby mode, it goes straight to showing the stream
4. Use remote control to up/down the channels hence the streams
5. What do you suggest about software? Kodi (XBMC) which has so many redundant features for me or a custom built?

I will also be thankful for suggestions on hardware in view of the above features. An Android STB or Raspberry Pi will be better?

Answer (score 1):

For a Raspberry Pi I would look into modifying an existing XBMC distro (i.e OpenElecy, XBian, etc.) for your needs. With some clever scripting using a startup script you should be able to achieve what you want.

For the hardware part (your point 1 and 4) you can use the RemotePi Board from [here](http://www.msldigital.com) (they have a model for the Raspberry Pi B+, too) to switch on and off and to control the channel up/down with a remote.

Booting time depends on the XBMC distro used, it is in the range of ranges 20s to 1 min.
Hope this helps...